# Derivation of Q in EM algorith

Tags: statistics, computer-science, computational-mathematics, expectation-maximization

Trying to learn EM Algorithms. Can someone explain the derivation steps they took to go from step 4.1 - 4.3. I am quite new to computational stats and it feels like I may be missing some fundamental concepts

[image]